# How to resize Chromium OS data partition to maximum?

Tags: partitioning, google-chrome-os

I've installed Chromium OS from https://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/?dir=daily by downloading an image file, uncompressing it, and writing the uncompressed image to the hard drive.

Chromium OS boots and works just fine. However, fdisk shows than only 2 GB is allocated for the data partition, even though the hard drive is much larger (>200 GB).

How do I get the data partition resized to the maxiumum possible size, so that it fills the hard disk?

I've tried:

- https://github.com/ethanmad/chromeos-resize , but it doesn't work: it tried to assign negative size to the ROOT-C partition.
- https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/partition-resizing says that *partition resizing is initiated by the system, not by the user.* How can I force this resize? (Also the page seems to be out of date, last update was in 2009.)

Answer (score 1):

before you flash your hdd make 2 partitions (first one for nonchromium os, second for blank space) make sure format of hdd is recognizable by unix>linux file system, flash first partition

Comment: The image I've downloaded is a full HDD image, already containing a partition table.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the this gh repo: [imperador/chromefy](https://github.com/imperador/chromefy). They have a dual boot script that should work for your case.